# How to tell if it is Wireless-G or Wireless-N that the iMac is using?

Tags: wifi

I sometimes see the iMac copying files from the PC wirelessly at a rate of 1.5MB/s and sometimes 2.5MB/s (by visually examining, because Mac doesn't seem to show what the speed is in the copy dialog).

Is there a way to find out whether my iMac is connected to the wired PC through the wireless router using Wireless-G or Wireless-N?  Can some app show and/or the terminal app show?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<kbd>Option</kbd> + click your menu bar's status icon.

[image]

Comment: interesting... quite many of the Mac functions are hidden and can be invoked using the Option key...

Comment: OPtion clicking the sound icon in the menubar also lets ur easily switch ur sound I/O

Comment: wow that is so useful!  no need to bring up the System Preferences every time

Comment: How did you grab that screenshot?

Comment: Commamd shift 4, then press space